# What is the explaination for this simple pointer program output

Tags: c, pointers

I tried to understand the size of address used to store variables and pointers, pointers-pointers and pointers-pointers-pointers. The results are kind of confusing.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    *** ppptr_string = NULL;
    int     *** ppptr_int    = NULL;
    double  *** ppptr_dbl    = NULL;

    char c=0; int i=0; double  d=0;

    printf("\n %d   %d   %d   %d   %d\n", sizeof(&ppptr_string),   
    sizeof(ppptr_string),  sizeof(*ppptr_string), sizeof(**ppptr_string), 
    sizeof(***ppptr_string));
    printf("\n %d   %d   %d   %d   %d\n", sizeof(&ppptr_int),   sizeof(ppptr_int),    
    sizeof(*ppptr_int),   sizeof(**ppptr_int),   sizeof(***ppptr_int));
    printf("\n %d   %d   %d   %d   %d\n", sizeof(&ppptr_dbl),   sizeof(ppptr_dbl),    
    sizeof(*ppptr_dbl),   sizeof(**ppptr_dbl),   sizeof(***ppptr_dbl));


    printf("\n  sizeof(char) = %d,   sizeof(int) = %d,   sizeof(double) = %d", 
    sizeof(c), sizeof(i), sizeof(d));
    printf("\n sizeof(&char) = %d,  sizeof(&int) = %d,  sizeof(&double) = %d", 
    sizeof(&c), sizeof(&i), sizeof(&d));

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Now the confusion. I can see that a variable address is always 2 bytes long on this machine. Regardless of type of the variable and regardless of the whether its a pointer variable. But why do I get size of 4 for so many entries in here? The pointer has size 4 always regardless of the type. The >address< at which the variable is stored is of size 2. And the content pointed to has a sized depending on the type.

Why do I get 4s in the output for sizeof??

My output from Borland C++ 5.02
[image]

Comment: conio.h? Is this an MS-DOS compiler?

Comment: please provide ouput for I don't get when you see 4s and when 2s.

Comment: If you get 4 for the pointer sizes, that's beause those kinds of pointers are 4 bytes on your machine. The language standard doesn't say what size a pointer should be.

Comment: Could you please add `sizeof(char*)`, `sizeof(double*)` and `sizeof(int*)`? Also, are you compiling a MS-DOS application? `sizeof(int) = 32` isn't really that common any more, what operation system do you use?

Comment: Would you please post the OS and version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a type `T` and a pointer on pointer like `T*** ptr`, then `ptr`, `*ptr`, `**ptr` are pointers themselves. You're probably working on a 32bit system (or compiling a 32bit application), so `sizeof(ptr) == sizeof(*ptr) == sizeof(**ptr)`:

```
--- Program output ---

 4   4   4   4   1

 4   4   4   4   4

 4   4   4   4   8

  sizeof(char) = 1,   sizeof(int) = 4,   sizeof(double) = 8
 sizeof(&char) = 4,  sizeof(&int) = 4,  sizeof(&double) = 4
```

`&ptr` is an address/a pointer on `T***`, so its size is 4 too. Only if you dereference the pointer to its maximum level (`***ptr`) you will have the actual type and not another pointer.

Comment: Yes I am using a 32 bit machine. Here is the output. I get all 2s in the first column and understand why. But the reason for getting 4s in the other columns makes no sense at all. The last row does not have 4s but 2s on machine since its 32 bit machine.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? I cannot recreate this behavior. Also the value `2` in the first column doesn't make any sense at all. An address on a 32bit system needs 32bit = 4 byte.

Comment: I am using Borland C++ 5.02 compiler. I created a DOS console Application. I don't know how to copy results from the black console window and put them here.

Comment: I have put the output at the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that you're getting near (16-bit) pointers for local variables, but a pointer declared as type * is a far (32-bit) pointer.

It's a quirk of working on a 16-bit Intel processor (or a 32-bit processor in "real mode"), e.g. in DOS, where you only have access to 1 MB of memory (or 640 kB in practice). The upper 16 bits of a far pointer are a segment (a 64k page in memory), and the lower 16 bits are an offset.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_are_near_far_and_huge_pointers_in_C

Answerers not able to reproduce this are most likely using a 32-bit (or more) OS on a 32-bit (or more) processor.